# Are there any considerable sanctions imposed against Belarus related to the Ukrainian invasion?

Tags: russian-federation, armed-conflict, ukraine, sanctions, belarus

In most of the news I hear about the West imposing sanctions against Russia in retaliation for the invasion, but have not read anything related to sanctions against Belarus.

Seeing that Belarus is actively helping Russia in the invasion, are there any major sanctions against Belarus already in place?